# Ext.js - Is it possible with open tooling and ext.js 7 to use es6 class syntax

Tags: extjs, ecmascript-6

Sencha announced on the Roadshow in 2017 that it should be possible to use es6/2015 class syntax.
The slides of the session are located here -> https://de.slideshare.net/senchainc/modernizing-the-ext-js-class-system-and-tooling.
But I dont get it to work.

Should it be possible with latest version of open tooling and ext.js 7?

If yes, how can i npm-install or reference to the correct ext.js (es6) modules needed in the import statements (f.e. `import { Ext, define } from "@extjs/core"`) ?

Are there any examples of an running ext.js app with es6 syntax?

THX in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! 
NodeJs (I assume) does not support ES6 out of the box, but take a look at this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-enable-es6-and-beyond-syntax-with-node-and-express-68d3e11fe1ab/) 
might help you out.

Comment: Thx Lasse! But I'm not using nodejs. Just npm as packagemanager for a ext.js (client / browser) project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in a blog post... 
https://www.sencha.com/blog/updates-to-sencha-roadmap/

It will be an ext.js 8.0 feature coming later this year.
At the moment it is only possible when using ExtAngular, ExtReact or ExtWebComponents.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I was just about to write you a comment on that blog post :) Good work with research :)

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can use `class` keyword today (started in v6.5 - see https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.7.0/guides/whats_new_cmd65.html).

What you cannot do is mix `class` with `Ext.define()` classes without some consequences. Those are not likely to be resolved any time soon, so just keep the worlds separate for safe measure: use `Ext.define()` to extends Ext JS classes; use `class` for your own classes if you like.

The important piece is build tooling.

If you need a transpiler, Sencha Cmd has Google Closure Compiler internally for that purpose. Using Sencha Cmd, you can build a single script bundle for your page that only includes the Ext JS classes your app needs. This will not allow you to use `import` or `export` to include ES6 modules in your app.

If you don't use Sencha Cmd, you can use the pre-built `ext-all.js` or `ext-all-debug.js` and include one of them via `<script>` tag in your markup file. From there, use webpack, rollup or whatever to build the rest of your code. You'll access the `Ext` object on the global scope but other code can be in modules.

On caveat there: in a module, `'use strict'` is enabled by default. This will not allow the `callParent()` method of Ext JS to determine the super class method, so you cannot use it. Likewise, the `statics()` method cannot be used, but that is seldom needed. Just be sure to test your code and avoid calling method that will not work in strict mode, or do not use strict mode (which is not an option if you use `import` and `export` keywords).